# Is there a way to find out if a barcode scanner is installed or plugged in a Windows 8.1 PC?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, barcode-scanner

i am developing a windows universal app using C# and xaml. My app uses barcode scanner to read the barcode values.

I want to know is there a way to find out if a barcode scanner is installed or plugged in a Windows 8.1 PC?

Anyone please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/867199/How-to-Build-a-Csharp-Barcode-QR-Code-Scanner-by-U

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your Scanner will be a USB device ? In which case I'd use the WMI library to enumerate your USB devices and look for the expected scanner device. The basics are shown here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/15/how-can-i-determine-which-usb-devices-are-connected-to-a-computer.aspx . Ultimately I think your user is going to need to let your application know at configuration time which device is the Barcode Scanner (you will have many USB devices) and you need to store the ID of the device in some config file, and re-use it later.

If you google "WMI USB C#" you should get a number of hits showing how to capture newly connected USB devices etc.

Comment: Hey Phillip, thanks for your reply. Can i get any solution in C#. It would be great if you can provide me something. Thanks in advance

Comment: I answered your question, I'm not doing the work for you :-)